# cost effective mobile data collection

Tags: java, php, mobile, sms, ussd

am having a task for developing an application that uses mobile phone in collection data and the client want to make use of cheapest mobile phone available in the market such as nokia N1280. The application is supposed to send data in a centralized server somewhere then web app for analysis and report generation. The web part there is no problem with me but am struggling to find the best and cost effective methods of collecting data from the field. s there anyone who has an idea of what method could be most effective of data collection? I thought of USSD but am not that familiar with it and am not sure how much it gonna cost my customer. text messages could be a good option but the problem is that it hard to control inputs from the user. Any help?
Thanx in advance..

Comment: What kind of data? In what country/countries and mobile networks?

Comment: am from East Africa(Tanzania).. the app is intended for statistical data on behaviour of the people such as how many people use mosqito net in a given area. Data will be colleceted each month of the year..

Comment: This will totally depend on what mobile providers (or resellers for mobile providers) are available in your country/region, what methods they offer and what rates they charge. It's probably going to be impossible to answer in a general way... SMS text messages might be the cheapest option. What do you mean by the input being hard to control?

Comment: Re your update on statistical data: That sounds like an ideal application for text messages, doesn't it? You could use *any* phone, no need for complex mobile applications and such. At least here in Germany, it would be the most cost-effective way.

Comment: here the mobile providers are tigo, vodacom and airtel guess they operate in Germany too if am not mistaken..What abt USSD app? what knowledge do i need to be able to create one? any resource?

Comment: by input being hard to control i mean it hard to restrict the user to enter only numbers for example if i need number of children in a certain area one can send me 123a..

Comment: As far as I understand USSD, you need the mobile provider's cooperation for it. I have no idea how much that would cost but my guess is way too much. Re validation, you would have to check incoming input anyway, no matter what you use - using USSD, you could input 99999999 children for esxample. If somebody sends an invalid value, you would have to send back a response asking for clarification. I'm no expert in the field but I'm fairly sure SMS is the ideal way

Answer (score 2):

mobile data collection in developing countries is a fairly well researched problem and there are existing free and open source solutions that have been shown to work at scale ([thousands of phones, millions of records](http://opendatakit.org/2011/05/carbon-for-water-collects-40000-forms-per-day-with-odk-and-monitors-results-from-international-space-station/)). try a site like [mobile active](http://mobileactive.org/go-to-mobile-data-collection-resources) to get a sense of the options.

my guess is that you'll likely settle on a [javarosa](https://bitbucket.org/javarosa/javarosa/wiki/Home)-based system like [open data kit](http://opendatakit.org) using $50-$100 phones and gprs for data.

disclaimer: i work on both javarosa and open data kit.

Comment: my client was using [link]episurveyor.org[/link] which requires java enabled mobile phone but he want to shift into using just normal mobile phone such as N1280..

Comment: episurveyor is also javarosa-based. very basic phones such as the n1280 are not easily programmable. sms is likely your best option. with a system like rapidsms, you should be able to do some input controls.